# Where can I practice web-security or network-security?

Tags: appsec, network, web-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Servers for penetration testing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/servers-for-penetration-testing)

I'm in a process of learning security of networks and websites.
I already practised code reviewing but I want to perform exercise.

Is there any online resources to get our hands dirty instead of just looking at code and word for learning web security or network security?

Comment: Hi @wizztjh, welcome to [security.se]! This question has been answered several times here already, in several different ways... see the linked question above.  Additionally, you can take a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/what-hacking-competitions-challenges-exist and especially http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/starting-with-sandbox-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you have a look at some of the wargames out there. For example one of my personal favourites is [Over the Wire](http://www.overthewire.org/wargames/) where they provide several games of varying difficulty. Certainly makes for a much more entertaining and thrilling learning experience.

Another one more specifically targeting web-hacking is [Hack This Site](http://www.hackthissite.org/) split into varying levels of difficulty.